# When does a broken pipe occur in a TCP stream?

Tags: tcp, rust, netcat

I am trying to write an echo server in Rust.

```
use std::net::{TcpStream, TcpListener};
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8000").unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();
        println!("A connection established");
        handle_connection(stream);
    }

}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 512];

    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

    println!("Request: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]));
    stream.write(&buffer[..]).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
}
```

The first request with `nc localhost 8000` is working as expected but subsequent request aren't. What am I doing wrong? Is the problem in how the server is reading requests from clients? Though there is no error server side.

I am sending data by typing them on the terminal:

```
$ nc localhost 8000
hi
hi
hello
# no response
# on pressing enter
Ncat: Broken pipe.
```

Comment: "but subsequent request aren't. " Please be specific. How are you sending data via `nc`? What exact error are you getting? You code seems to work for me.

Comment: @loganfsmyth
I am sending data by typing them on the terminal. Updated the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A 'Broken pipe' message happens when you write to a stream where the other end has been closed.  In your example, your `handle_connection` routine reads a single buffer from the client, copies that back to the client, and then returns, which will close the stream.  When you run `netcat` from the terminal like that, the terminal defaults to line buffering, so each line you type will be sent to the server as a single write.

The first line is sent, read by the server, echoed back, and then the server closes the connection.  Netcat gets a second line, writes that to the socket, and gets a 'Broken pipe' because the server has closed the connection.

If you want your server to read multiple messages, you need to have your `handle_connection` routine loop, reading from the stream until it gets an EOF.